# Azure table storage - partitionkey design for fast queries

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

We are storing our log entries into Azure table storage. We are storing the following properties:

- date (DateTime)
- tenantId (long)
- username (string)
- severity (int - enumeration of Error (0), Warning (1), Info (2), Debug(3))
- ... other properties which are not important right now

There's a huge amount of log entries and we would like to query the logs fast according to following columns:

- date (from/to)
- tenantId (equals)
- severity (from/to)
- username (equals)

So we designed our rowKey to be date + guid to guarantee uniqueness. And now we need to design PartitionKey. We need to be able to query according to tenantId, username and severity. So we need to get them to PartitionKey I suppose.

Following format: {severity}-{tenantId}-{username} seems to be a candidate (example of a key is 1-500-me@me.com which means severity: Warning, tenantId: 500, user: me@me.com). For instance I would like to query for:

- Debug and Info severity

that's fine because I can write `PartitionKey >= 2 AND PartitionKey < 4`, - it will reduce all results of other severity.

But if I need to enhance this query for tenantId = 500 (so Debug and Info for tenantId 500 only), I need to write `PartitionKey >= 2-500 AND PartitionKey < 2-501 AND PartitionKey >= 3-500 AND PartitionKey < 3-501`

So it seems possible, but query gets more complicated. I know I can only benchmark to test its performance, but the question is whether is there any better design of RowKey and PartitionKey to achieve better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Recommended approach would be to add multiple rows for the same data with different PartitionKeys. For example, if you have following data:

> date: 2017-07-31
>
> tenantId: 3
>
> severity: 2
>
> username: me@me.com

Here's how your data should be stored in the table:

```
PartitionKey    RowKey  date        tenantId    severity    user
----------------------------------------------------------------------
D|2017-07-31    GUID()  2017-07-31  500         2           me@me.com
T|500           GUID()  2017-07-31  500         2           me@me.com
S|2             GUID()  2017-07-31  500         2           me@me.com
U|me@me.com     GUID()  2017-07-31  500         2           me@me.com
```

So when you need to query on say tenant id and severity, you would do something like:

```
PartitionKey eq 'T|500' and severity eq 2
```

or

```
PartitionKey eq 'S|2' and tenant eq 500
```

Comment: that's clever, because you always go through single partition only, which should be fast (am I right?), i am only wondering about the negative impact of inserting quadruple more records (but if it is async task, it should not have negative impact on UX)

Comment: `that's clever, because you always go through single partition only, which should be fast (am I right?)` - That's correct. `i am only wondering about the negative impact of inserting quadruple more records (but if it is async task, it should not have negative impact on UX)` - Normally you would do this through a background process as you will be performing 4 operations against table storage and it is quite possible that one or more of them might fail so you would want to ensure that all records get inserted properly.

Comment: yeah, that's an option - I am only affraid about 'hot partition' problem described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide ... but currently we are also putting log entries to single partition (day is the partition) and we do not experience problems. Have you ever had a problem related to 'hot partition' when storing logs into table storage? Also what about storing them to blob, have you tried that? I am wondering about the ease of their querying then (download and parse file is required).

Comment: The problem is that you can only do certain operation when filtering by partition key. Using your original approach, you need to pick one attribute to be the most predominant and use it at the first part of the composed key. After that, you can quickly find records the meets any criteria related to this field but for the other (without providing the main field) the search will be slow.

Comment: Really, aren't you then storing 4x the amount of data?

Comment: @dinotom - That's correct but then table storage is extremely cheap.

Comment: And a row cannot have identical partition & row keys as any other row, correct?

Comment: @dinotom - That's correct. Think of partition key + row key as the primary key.